# Unable to Fetch backend from frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to set up a repo by forking it. I installed all the npm packages and all the necessary changes to start the development server in the frontend as well as backend. But when I hit the POST route, it sends me some weird error.

Frontend .env File

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL="https://127.0.0.1:2222"
REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_URL="https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/sagar-barapatre/upload"
```

index.js

```js
export const client = (endpoint, { body, ...customConfig } = {}) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };

  if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }

  const config = {
    method: body ? "POST" : "GET",
    ...customConfig,
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      ...customConfig.headers,
    },
  };

  if (body) {
    config.body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }
  return fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}${endpoint}`, config).then(
    async (res) => {
      const data = await res.json();

      if (res.ok) {
        return data;
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(data);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

When I try to signup, it's showing unable to fetch `POST https://127.0.0.1:2222/auth/signup`
`net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I am trying to hit the post request and below is the code for signup.js

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { client } from "../utils";
import { FormWrapper } from "./Login";
import useInput from "../hooks/useInput";
import { UserContext } from "../context/UserContext";

import logo from "../assets/logo.png";
const Signup = ({ login }) => {
  const { setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const email = useInput("");
  const fullname = useInput("");
  const username = useInput("");
  const password = useInput("");

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!email.value || !password.value || !username.value || !fullname.value) {
      return toast.error("Please fill in all the fields");
    }

    if (username.value === "explore") {
      return toast.error(
        "The username you entered is not acceptable, try again"
      );
    }

    const re = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
    if (re.exec(username.value) === null) {
      return toast.error(
        "The username you entered is not acceptable, try again"
      );
    }

    const body = {
      email: email.value,
      password: password.value,
      username: username.value,
      fullname: fullname.value,
    };

    try {
      const { token } = await client("/auth/signup", { body });
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    } catch (err) {
      return toast.error(err.message);
    }

    const user = await client("/auth/me");
    setUser(user.data);
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user.data));

    fullname.setValue("");
    username.setValue("");
    password.setValue("");
    email.setValue("");
  };

  return (
    <FormWrapper onSubmit={handleLogin}>
      <img src={logo} alt="logo" />

      <form>
        <input
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email.value}
          onChange={email.onChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Full Name"
          value={fullname.value}
          onChange={fullname.onChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username"
          value={username.value}
          onChange={username.onChange}
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password.value}
          onChange={password.onChange}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Sign up" className="signup-btn" />
      </form>

      <div>
        <p>
          Already have an account? <span onClick={login}>Login</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </FormWrapper>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

I encountered this error for the first time in my life.
Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: Can you try with `http://127.0.0.1:2222/`, instead of `https://127.0.0.1:2222/` ? It seems your SSL is not valid. If you use secure SSL 'https' , both frontend and backend servers must be `https`. If one of them is `http` or `https`, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

just **replace https to http** in the react env variables for api call url

```
 REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL="http://127.0.0.1:2222"
```

you have to setup ssl certificate in the api server for using the https

Comment: Can you please tell me how to set up an SSL certificate? I don't know this.

Comment: I don't how to setup the SSL certificate in local but you can setup SSL certificate in live server by following the tutorials that are available on various websites.